# How to lower the scope of a transaction

Tags: orientdb

[In the discussion in one of the enhancement proposals for Version 3.0](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-labs/issues/10#issuecomment-248839828), an example was mentioned about a query that represents a mass update of the database, but within a transaction (ie an atomic mass update). The current issue of such an update is, if the database is very big, it could cause an OOM error to occur.

The suggestion to fix this problem is to stop ODB from failing with the OOM error and to rollback the transaction and give the user a warning of the imminent OOM and to ask the user to lower the scope of the transaction.

My question is: How would a user lower the scope of such a mass update transaction?

Scott

Answer (score 1):

You may use limit keyword which works with update http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Update.html . You may limit by query execution timeout and by an amount of records updated during execution of a query.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Couldn't ODB do the limiting itself? I have no clue about how this could work internally, but say there is X free memory, couldn't ODB then say, "Ok, let's take 25% of that memory and allow this mass update to happen until that portion of the RAM is used up, once it is, flush the results, wash, rinse and repeat until the update is completed." 

Or let me ask another question. How can userland know that an update query might cause the server to hit an OOM warning? Does that mean all queries need to be programmatically batched in advance just to make sure ODB doesn't implode?

Comment: Unfortunately now you should check your big queries in advance, but we have issue which will fix given problem https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5720

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Does OEP10 also take that issue into account? If not, should it?

Comment: No, it should not. But issue which I provided takes it into account